# Table value parameter to joinable IQueryable

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

So for various reasons we need to send a large list of Ids to a EF6 query.

```
queryable.Where(x => list.Contains(x.Id));
```

is not ideal since it will create a huge were list.

So I was thinking, would it be possible some homehow to pass a table value parameter with the ids and get a IQueryable back that I can join against?

something like (Pseudo code)

```
var queryable = TableValueToIQueryable<MyTableValueType>(ids);
context.Set<MyEntity>().Join(queryable, x => x.Id, x.Value, (entity, id) => entity);
```

Is this possible somehow?

**update:** I have been able to use `EntityFramework.CodeFirstStoreFunctions` to execute a sql function and map the data to `IQueryable<MyEntity>`. it uses `CreateQuery` and `ObjectParameters`, can I use table value params somehow with ObjectParamters?

**update2:** Set().SqlQuery(...) will work with Table value parameters, but the resulting DbSqlQuery is not Joinable in SQL with a IQueryably so the result will be two connections and the join is done in memory

```
var idResult = Set<IdFilter>().SqlQuery("select * from GetIdFilter(@ids)", parameter);
var companies = idResult.Join(Set<tblCompany>(), x => x.Id, y => y.CompanyID, (filter, company) => company).ToList();
```

**update3:** ExecuteStoreQuery

```
 ((IObjectContextAdapter)ctx).ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<InvoicePoolingContext.IdFilter>("select * from dbo.GetIdFilter(@ids)", parameter)
   .Join(ctx.Set<tblCompany>(), x => x.Id, y => y.CompanyID, (filter, company) => company).ToList();
```

Gives error:

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which
>   must be closed first.

Comment: you can enable MARS to circumvent your error ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h32h3abf(v=vs.110).aspx )
but this will result in the join being performed in the memory of your .Net client

Comment: Then it equals to update2 solution basically :/